# Is there a longer version of "Jipi and the Paranoid Chip"?

Tags: neal-stephenson

In the version of "Jipi and the Paranoid Chip" that appears [online](http://www.vanemden.com/books/neals/jipi.html), there's a note at the top: "(excerpt as appeared in Forbes, July 7, 1997)." Was the version that appeared in *Forbes* an excerpt of a longer version? Has the story ever been published anywhere excerpt *Forbes*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place I can find any published information for "[Jipi and the Paranoid chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jipi_and_the_Paranoid_Chip)" (AKA "[Jipi's Day at the Office](http://www.vanemden.com/books/neals/jipi.html)") is in [Forbes Magazine](http://business.highbeam.com/articles/392705/forbes/july-1997) with various copies of the same length story being found on the internet

If a longer version does exist, it's never been officially published. The copyright for the story is held by Forbes and in his book "[Some Remarks](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=R4gzxyR0y08C&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=jipi%20and%20the%20paranoid%20chip&source=bl&ots=lKplrEYANj&sig=cDpiNNgAU230bWy0UYMvRD8dJeg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3YTtUqugM6vX7AbmoYHwCA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBjgU#v=onepage&q=jipi&f=false)", Neal refers to 'Jipi and the Paranoid Chip' as being

> "extraordinarily ponderous and labored upon rereading and so has been
>   left out [of future publications of his short fiction]".

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the list of articles in that issue of Forbes.